# Snapshot Debugging: Failed to get response from URL

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, when following the simple steps to attach a Snapshot Debugger, I get:

> Error: Failed to get response from URL:
>
> http://mysite-service:443/

I have no clue where the debugger extension is getting this URL from, nor this port, as my App Service in Azure is:

https://mysite-service.appname-service.appserviceenvironment.net

How can I fix where the Snapshot Debugger service is trying to magically inject this url? I have been unable to find a single source with this same issue.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: @JasonPan Thank you so much for following up. I havent had a chance to review the solution below but will shortly and get back to you. Again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

After my test, the IDE I use is `Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.8.2`. Everything is normal with the Snapshot Debugger function.

[image]

**Suggested troubleshooting steps:**

1. It is recommended to upgrade vs2019 to the latest version and continue to try.
2. Enable Debugging on portal.

[image]

3. According to the official documents, compare the error information specifically and find solutions.

   [Troubleshooting and known issues for snapshot debugging in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-apps-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019)

***Related posts or tutorial references:***

[1. [ Tutorial ] Getting Started with Snapshot Debugger](https://www.azurebarry.com/getting-started-with-snapshot-debugger/)

[2. Get the following error when attaching to SnapShot Debugger - Error --- Failed to get response from URL: https://management.azure.com//subscriptions](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/593054/get-the-following-error-when-attaching-to-snapshot.html)